# Updating a document in firebase with an auto generated ID

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I've learned how to add and delete from Firebase. It's quite straightforward.

My delete code which is activated when clicking the delete button, it's found in my adapter class (it's the only way I could get the delete button click registered correctly)

```
public void deleteJournal(int position) {
        getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
}
```

And to add (which is in another class)

```
CollectionReference diaryRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("Diary");
        diaryRef.add(new Diary(growName, description, priority));
```

But I don't even know where to begin to update. I will be putting the edit code in the adapter class which will open a dialog window to edit values.

I know how to create the window and edit the values and set new variables for this data. But how do I make sure I'm applying this updated data to the document with the corresponding edit button that clicked? Then update Firebase correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
diaryRef.add(new Diary(growName, description, priority)).addOnSuccessListener(documentReference -> {
                        String id = documentReference.getId();
                        db.collection("Diary").document(id).update("entryId", id);
                    });
```

now you will have a unique id to delete or update the entry

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

> But how do I make sure I'm applying this updated data to the document

In the same way, you are deleting the document. Please see the method below:

```
public void updateJournal(int position) {
    Diary diary = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).toObject(Diary.class);
    //Make the changes
}
```

Once you have the `Diar`y object, you can make the desired updates and then write the document back to the database, as shown in your question.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, thanks, I wish I could mark both right, as they both helped me